# Compiling GCC 6.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

Command I have used the following commands to build GCC 6.1:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libmpfr-dev libgmp3-dev libgmp-dev libmpc-dev flex bison libisl-dev
wget http://nl.mirror.babylon.network/gcc/releases/gcc-6.1.0/gcc-6.1.0.tar.bz2 -O - | tar xjvf -
cd gcc-6.1.0
./configure --enable-shared --disable-checking --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
make -j4
```

When trying to compile GCC 6.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 / x86_64 I get the following error.

```
libtool: link:  /home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc -nostdinc++ -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include     -fPIC -DPIC -D_GLIBCXX_SHARED -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/crtbeginS.o  .libs/compatibility.o .libs/compatibility-debug_list.o .libs/compatibility-debug_list-2.o .libs/compatibility-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-thread-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-chrono.o .libs/compatibility-condvar.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a ../src/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a ../src/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -lm -L/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lc -lgcc_s /home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/crtendS.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z -Wl,relro   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libstdc++.so.6 -o .libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a(cow-sstream-inst.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTCSt18basic_stringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE16_St13basic_ostreamIwS1_E' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:606: recipe for target 'libstdc++.la' failed
make[6]: *** [libstdc++.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/user/build/gcc-6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src'
```

The problematic line seems to be this one:

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   ../src/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a(cow-sstream-inst.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol
>   `_ZTCSt18basic_stringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE16_St13basic_ostreamIwS1_E'
>   can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

It says `recompile with -fPIC`, but I can't seem to find the `./configure` flag which makes sure `libc++11convenience` gets built with `-fPIC`.

I have been searching for a solution, but couldn't find anything. What should I do at this point to successfully compile gcc6.1?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the GCC [install instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). GCC should not be built inside its source tree:

> First, we highly recommend that GCC be built into a separate directory from the sources which does not reside within the source tree.

You should try again, perhaps something like:

```
wget \
 http://nl.mirror.babylon.network/gcc/releases/gcc-6.1.0/gcc-6.1.0.tar.bz2 -O - \
  | tar xjvf -
mkdir Gcc6BuildTree
cd Gcc6BuildTree
../gcc-6.1.0/configure --enable-shared --disable-checking \
  --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-6
make -j4
```

BTW, try first `/usr/bin/gcc -v`; that will give you how the *system* compiler was configured & built. And it is inspirational.

Also, I strongly recommend using `--program-suffix=` (and I would recommend configuring also the [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/))

And you might try first to run `aptitude build-dep gcc-6` (or `gcc-5`) to get the useful dependencies (dependencies for GCC 6 have much in common with dependencies for GCC 5).

Perhaps your Ubuntu already ships with some `gcc-6`? Did you try `aptitude install gcc-6` ? See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746480/64680).

Also [GCC 6.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) was released a few weeks ago (in august 2016). You'll better build gcc 6.2 instead of gcc 6.1

Notice also that the source tarball has a [contrib/download_prerequisites](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/contrib/download_prerequisites?view=markup) script which you might find useful.

NB: `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` might be a better place to ask your question.